Are compiled bindings disabled when using StaticResource for Source?
Quoted from the official documentation title Compiled bindings:

Important
Compiled bindings are disabled for any binding expressions that define the Source property. This is because the Source property is always set using the x:Reference markup extension, which can't be resolved at compile time.
In addition, compiled bindings are currently unsupported on multi-bindings.

I don't understand why Source property is always set using x:Reference while we know that we can also use Source={StaticResource xyz}, for example. So in this case are compiled bindings disabled too?

Compiled Bindings will be disabled if you use Source, Since Compiled Bindings run on the Assumption that the Source is the same for the whole ContentPage, until a Binding says otherwise, I recommend you read my blog here its all you need to read to understand compiled bindings https://blog.stackademic.com/leveraging-the-power-of-compiled-bindings-in-net-maui-4b3db6b9f4cb

You should say that ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Source={x:Reference this}}" disables compiled binding in your blog but you did not say that. Why?

Because it does not disable Compiled Bindings for the page, but just that one property, which is not exactly "disabling" it

While the documentation singles out x:Reference it's not the exclusive example. I think the point is if you're using Source then, you're not able to use compiled bindings. The workaround, of course, would be to set BindingContext instead, e.g.
<Label
    x:DataType="Entry"
    BindingContext="{StaticResource myEntry}"
    Text="Hello World"
    TextColor="{Binding TextColor}">
    <Label.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Entry x:Key="myEntry" TextColor="Green" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Label.Resources>
</Label>

